# loop through parent items in Web part

Tags: 2010

I have a share point page that has 2 web parts.  **Webpart1** and **webpart2**.  Webpart1 contains a custom webpart that reads the username and login, I display this information in label1.  Wepart2(pageviewer) contains an asp (classic) page to fill a form, this page resides in a different server on same network.   Is there a way to add some javascript or vbscript that I can add to the asp page that when it loads I can get the Username and login from the webpart1 and pass it to webpart2?  If anyone has done this can you guys post an example ?

Thank you,

Jesús Ibarra.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to pass username and login through [querystring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/querystring) on your iframe, something like `<iframe src="//yourotherserver.domain/Yourpage.aspx?username=<username>&login=<login>">`.

There are several ways you can achieve this, for example **Webpart1** could render the iframe (instead of using **webpart2**), you can see some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015070/using-iframes-in-asp-net).

Another alternative is to use JavaScript to change the `src`-attribute of your `iframe` tag on Page Viewer Web Part, which means you don't need **Webpart1** at all.
Here is an example of what I mean:

```
// Your Page Viewer Web Part iframe will have an ID like this:
var iframeId = 'MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ4'; 
var iframe = document.getElementById(iframeId);
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var user = ctx.get_web().get_currentUser();
ctx.load(user);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
  iframe.src = iframe.src + '?username=' + user.get_title() + 
      '&login=' + user.get_loginName();
});
```